# Discord.js | How to make a loop message every 24 hours / a day with a variable?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm here trying to make a Discord Bot with NodeJS or Discord.js. I want to make a message that sends every day, but with a variable that increases by 1 every day too, so like day 1: Yeet 1, day 2: Yeet 2, and so on.

But however, I have no idea how to do that, Well because I am new to Discord.js. Here's my code:

```
const discord = require("discord.js");

var client = new discord.Client();

client.on('message', function(message) {
    // Now, you can use the message variable inside
    if (message.content === "$loop") {
        daytime = 0;
        var interval = setInterval (function () {
            dayResult = daytime + 1;
            // use the message's channel (TextChannel) to send a new message
            message.channel.send("quack " + dayResult)
            .catch(console.error); // add error handling here
        }, 86400 * 1000); 
        
    }
});
```

1 day = 86400 seconds if I'm right.
It would be really helpful if you helped me.

Comment: 86400 * 1000 means 1000 days.

Comment: @Jakye I'm pretty sure it equals one day.

Comment: My bad. I've counted 86400 as seconds, not as ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making a new variable, you should just be incrementing it with the [++ Operator](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-unary-operators/)

```js
var daytime = 0;
var interval = setInterval(() => {
 message.channel
  .send(`quack ${++daytime}`) // increment the variable
  .catch(console.error); // add error handling here
}, 86400 * 1000);
```

---

Code Snippet Example:

```js
var stopwatch = 0;

setInterval(() => console.log(`It's been ${++stopwatch} second(s)`), 1000);
```

Comment: If you can't stop it with `ctrl + c`, I don't think the code is the problem.

Comment: Didn't you set the `setInterval` to one day?

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of your bot running at once? That would explain both of the problems. Try restarting your computer.

Comment: No, i don't have multiple instance, i used to have this problem with multiple instance, now this thing is spamming without multiple instance